# any way to show the button in highlight mode

Tags: iphone, uibutton, highlighting

i hav a more buttons on my scrool view so if one of them clickrd i just want to highlight the button untill the any of the button clicked again....

so i just want to show the button in clicked mode......

thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the button's highlighted property to YES:

```
myButton.highlighted = YES;
```

Comment: but my button has the images as background and button image

Comment: If the button is an instance of UIButton or of a subclass of UIButton, it should indicate its highlighted state as expected. I may have misunderstood your question completely, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use these two lines:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
myButton.highlighted = YES;
```

Dont use:

```
[myButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
```

This will hide the highlighting of button.